How to Configure the Pre-installed WireGuard Client on Ubuntu 24.04 via Network Manager
I'm currently running Ubuntu 24.04 and I've noticed that WireGuard is already integrated with Network Manager by default. I would like to configure WireGuard as a client on my system, but I'm unsure about the steps to do so.
Specifically, I'm looking for a guide on:
How to configure WireGuard through the Network Manager GUI.
How to generate the necessary keys for WireGuard.
I have some knowledge of the command line but would prefer a GUI-based solution if possible. If there are any existing guides or step-by-step instructions, that would be extremely helpful.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Would this help https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/introduction-to-wireguard-vpn? actually you can also get it configured by using Import from a File in network manager.

@amar The article you sent me is more than 3 years old, definitely written before Ubuntu 24.04, and it mentions the installation of (wireguard-tools: wg and wg-quick). I'd like to understand if it's necessary to install them or if there is something already included by default. I can't find any information on this. Do you have Ubuntu 24.04?

I do. Logik indicates that only those keys that are present in the Network Manager GUI, Wiregaurd can be used for Network Manager installation of Wiregaurd. If you need more settings then you should install Wiregaurd and wireguard-tools. I did not see any wg-quick when i ran `apt search wireguard´.

Are you still looking for an answer or have you figured it out? Are you trying to connect to your own Wireguard server/peer or a commercial VPN service provider. If it is another provider they may create a config file for you. You just import the config file.

in the network manager, click "plus" and add the configuration file that formed the wireguard server. You can add as many profiles as you need. Profiles will appear automatically, you do not need to fill in anything.

My server, in example don't produce configuration files and I'd want to configure parametrer via GUI (if gui exists, there would be a reason why!). GUI is bugged and dont'let to "apply" when all filed are filled, plus if you loose focus on the "peer" configuration window, it closes, so you can't use copy-paste for keys and address.
Big fail.

I'm not sure I understood your problem correctly.   The Ubuntu Network Manager (VPN wireguard) is intended only for configuring the VPN client, not the server. VPN server configuration is performed by running a script (hundreds of them on github), these scripts will create a settings file for VPN clients.
